# Change direction of table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset [lipid] that extracted from electronic medical record system (EMRS). In that EMRS, the physician give order to obtain a laboratory blood profile from a patient with a unique order number **BUT** with a different service types. So, if one order has 4 service types, EMRS will record the event on 4 rows (identical [duplicates] order number in Order_no column, **BUT** with a different service types in Service_type column) like this;

| Order_no | Service_type | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TC | 230 |
| 1 | HDL | 40 |
| 1 | TG | 150 |
| 1 | LDL | 90 |

Sometimes, one order may has <4 service types, hence, order will be like that;

| Order_no | Service_type | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TC | 230 |
| 1 | HDL | 40 |
| 1 | TG | 150 |
| 1 | LDL | 90 |
| 2 | TC | 230 |
| 2 | HDL | 40 |
| 4 | TC | 230 |
| 4 | HDL | 40 |
| 4 | LDL | 90 |
| 5 | TC | 230 |
| 5 | TG | 150 |
| 5 | LDL | 90 |
| 6 | TC | 230 |
| 8 | TC | 230 |
| 8 | HDL | 40 |
| 8 | TG | 150 |
| 8 | LDL | 90 |

What I'm trying to do is writing a query that keeps Order_no column and change direction of table as well as merge **identical** order number in one row like this;

| Order_no | TC | HDL | TG | LDL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 230 | 40 | 150 | 90 |
| 2 | 250 | 66 |  |  |
| 4 | 199 | 39 |  | 99 |
| 5 | 299 | 45 |  | 190 |
| 6 | 400 |  |  |  |
| 8 | 400 | 40 | 250 | 290 |

How can I write this query in Google BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select * from your_table
pivot (any_value(Result) for Service_type in ('TC', 'HDL', 'TG', 'LDL'))
```

In case if Service Type is not known in advance  - you can use below

```
execute immediate (select '''
select * from your_table
pivot (any_value(Result) for Service_type in (''' || string_agg(distinct "'" || Service_type || "'") || 
"))"
from your_table
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PIVOT`.

Example:

```sql
WITH your_table AS 
( 
  SELECT 1 AS Order_no, 'TC' AS Service_type, 230 AS Result
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'HDL', 40
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'TG', 150
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'LDL', 90
)

SELECT *
FROM your_table PIVOT(SUM(Result) FOR Service_type IN ('TC', 'HDL', 'TG', 'LDL'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much dnnshssm, I think approach suggested by Mikhail above is simpler