# How to transform rows into different columns in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, transform, multiple-columns

For short, I have this nested fields that I'd like to separate into different columns.

Here's my table now:

| transaction_id | transaction_name | transaction_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | item_1 | 200 |
| 123 | item_2 | 100 |
| 124 | item_1 | 200 |
| 124 | item_2 | 300 |
| 124 | item_3 | 400 |

And here's the output that I'd like to have

| transaction_id | transaction_name_1 | transaction_amount_1 | transaction_name_2 | transaction_amount_2 | transaction_name_3 | transaction_amount_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | item_1 | 200 | item_2 | 100 | NULL | NULL |
| 124 | item_1 | 200 | item_2 | 300 | item_3 | 400 |

Does anyone has the solution for this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *PIVOT* query :

```sql
SELECT * FROM sample_table
 PIVOT (
   ANY_VALUE(transaction_name) transaction_name,
   ANY_VALUE(transaction_amount) transaction_amount 
   FOR transaction_name IN ('item_1' `1`, 'item_2' `2`, 'item_3' `3`)
 );
```

**Query results**

[image]

Using a dynamic sql:

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(FORMAT("""
  SELECT * FROM sample_table
   PIVOT (
     ANY_VALUE(transaction_name) transaction_name,
     ANY_VALUE(transaction_amount) transaction_amount 
     FOR transaction_name IN ('%s')
   );""", (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT transaction_name, "','") FROM sample_table))
);
```

Comment: Hi Jaytiger, thanks for the solution. Actually it worked for the case above, thanks to you. However, in my actual case, I have thousand or even millions of items, it is impossible to put it in FOR ... IN () clause. Is there any way to automate that? Let me know if I need to ask another question.

Comment: @IrenRamadhan, You can find the generic solution using a dynamic sql by Mikhail or by me below.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72869053/change-direction-of-table-in-bigquery
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74327529/bigquery-best-way-to-transpose-rows-into-multiple-columns

I've updated answer so you can see how it looks like.
But you should note that there are some limitation in numbers of items which you can pivot.