# Bigquery - Transposing Rows into Multiple Cells but not using cell values name as column name

Tags: google-bigquery, pivot, row, multiple-columns, transpose

Previously I've asked a question within this [link](https://lookerstudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/ea3d900f-94c8-4243-b9bf-f2610df35cde/page/xUrED) and has been successfully answered by [JayTiger's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74327529/bigquery-best-way-to-transpose-rows-into-multiple-columns) and [Mikhail's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72869053/change-direction-of-table-in-bigquery)

Their answers helped my issue successfully, but I have another case that cannot be solved by those ones.

For example, I have this kind of data:

| transaction_id | item_name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | snacks |
| 123 | marbles |
| 124 | tooth_paste |
| 124 | tooth_brush |
| 124 | pen |

By using [JayTiger's Answer]
([Bigquery - Best way to transpose rows into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74327529/bigquery-best-way-to-transpose-rows-into-multiple-columns)) and [Mikhail's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72869053/change-direction-of-table-in-bigquery) it will generate list of **columns** like below

| transaction_id | item_name_snacks | item_name_marbles | item_name_tooth_paste | item_name_tooth_brush | item_name_pen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

However, what I desired is something like this where I can define the name of the columns by using a sequence of number for example:

| transaction_id | item_name_1 | item_name_2 | item_name_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | snacks | marbles |  |
| 124 | tooth_paste | tooth_brush | pen |

Since in my sample data the maximum number of item per transaction_id is 3 items, then the generated column is also 3.

Is there any way to pull this off? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider below and I think you can generalize the query using a dynamic sql answered by Mikhail and me in previous answers.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT '123' transaction_id, 'snacks' item_name UNION ALL
  SELECT '123' transaction_id, 'marbles' item_name UNION ALL
  SELECT '124' transaction_id, 'tooth_paste' item_name UNION ALL
  SELECT '124' transaction_id, 'tooth_brush' item_name UNION ALL
  SELECT '124' transaction_id, 'pen' item_name
)
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_id) rn FROM sample_table)
 PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(item_name) item_name FOR rn IN (1, 2, 3));
```

**Query results**

[image]

For a dynamic sql, you can refere to the following.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample_table AS
  SELECT '123' transaction_id, 'snacks' item_name UNION ALL
  SELECT '123' transaction_id, 'marbles' item_name UNION ALL
  SELECT '124' transaction_id, 'tooth_paste' item_name UNION ALL
  SELECT '124' transaction_id, 'tooth_brush' item_name UNION ALL
  SELECT '124' transaction_id, 'pen' item_name;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_id) rn FROM sample_table)
   PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(item_name) item_name FOR rn IN (%s))
  """, (SELECT STRING_AGG('' || rn, ',') FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_id) rn 
            FROM sample_table ORDER BY rn
       )));
```

- `'' || rn` is same as `CAST(rn AS STRING)`

Comment: Hi Jaytiger, thank you very much for the help. But I still couldn't figure out how to change those hardcode rn IN (1, 2, 3) into dynamic query. If you don't mind, could you please share the exact example? Thank you in advance

Comment: @IrenRamadhan, I've updated answer. kindly check that out.

Comment: Thanks @Jaytiger, it works very well. Is there any way for me to CREATE TEMP TABLE for the result from "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT"?

Comment: Simply you can add `CREATE TEMP TABLE table_name AS ` right before `SELECT *`. Try it and get back to me if you still have a problem with it.

Comment: Done, I initially tried using it right before EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. Now, I am able to do it, thanks @Jaytiger